# Mobile browser automation

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, appium

can we automate mobile browsers without using any emulators or real devices and directly using a web browser?

I know we can use appium to test mobile browsers but for that, we need to have either emulator or real device

I have a web test framework and I want to use the same for mobile browser testing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with web browser, using selenium, only you should do to set the dimension size of your mobile:

**for example:** `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));`

Answer (score 0):

Potentially yes. However, with a lot of limitations and extra efforts.
You may use the Chrome Dev Tools Mobile Emulation for that:

[image]

See [this article](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation) for details

Answer (score 0):

Selenium allows for remote automation and is supported by both chrome and firefox browsers. Steps for chrome automation in android are:
Enable usb debugging in phone and connect it to pc or laptop
Install python and selenium and android sdk in pc or laptop

```
adb start-server
adb shell su -c chmod 777 /data/local
./chromedriver
```

Above commands will display a port number. Just note it down as it will be required further.
Then start automation. Below is small example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

```
                                                    OR
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = {
 'chromeOptions': {
   'androidPackage': 'com.android.chrome',
                   }
                }
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:9515', capabilities) # Specify your port number value 
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

Both google chrome stable and beta apps available from play store are supported.

Same can be done with firefox and gecko driver. Just change Chrome in above code worh Firefox and chromedriver with geckodriver.
Hope it helped you.

Comment: but we are using a real device here right for automation? the automation is happening on a mobile device.

Comment: In my explanation too real chrome browser app installed in smartphone is being automated and not any kind of virtual device or emulator

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response. My query was how to automate without using any real device or emulator. Like simulating the web browser in laptop. Kind of responsiveness testing

Comment: Use bluestack to emulate android on laptop. or creare virtual android using sdk

Comment: But whats the difference between mobile browser and pc browser unless both are on different devices.